# How to measure my local network traffic and load?

Tags: network-monitoring, local-area-network

I have a small local network that share an internet connection through a simple wireless router.

I would like to measure how every computer is using the local and external bandwidth and how much data each computer downloaded from the external network.

Is there an application that I could install on my computer to measure this?

Comment: I see you used the [network-monitoring](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/network-monitoring) tag.  Have you tried looking at any of those questions and seeing if any of the tools work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ntop.. It perfectly suffices for this type of thing.. :D

Answer (score 0):

MRTG is also made for the task, but is a little more involved to setup:
http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Answer (score 0):

[PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) is a Windows port of the venerable MRTG and extends the functionality to other types of monitoring. It is free unless you want to monitor more than 20 devices.